# How to download CDH4 setup manually

Tags: hadoop

How can I download the CDH4 setup manually?

I mean I want to download the setup without using apt-get from the ubuntu command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDH4 is Cloudera's distribution of Apache Hadoop. CDH is a collection of Apache Hadoop and several components of its ecosystem.

Assuming that you are requesting for the source, each component can be downloaded as a tarball from the following location:
[CDH Packaging and Tarball Information](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_3.html)